# JS __proto__ inheritance replacement

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I m using prototype inheritance as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto

```
function MyString(data){this.data = data ;}
MyString.prototype = { data : null,
 toString: function(){ return this.data ;}
} ;

MyString.prototype.__proto__ = String.prototype ;
```

Now I can use String functions and MyString functions on MyString instances.

But since `__proto__` is deprecated, non standard and should be avoided, what would be the best way to inherists objects ?

I found http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ and it still looks a bit complex and somewhat overkill, compared to a single-line code :)

Edit: Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 6):

The ECMAScript 5 specification includes a new function `Object.create()` that allows you to create a generic object with a specific prototype.  To get the behaviour you want you'd do:

```
MyString.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype)
MyString.prototype.toString = ....
```

`Object.create` can be used to create an arbitrarily long prototype chain, simply by chain return values along.  Unfortunately it doesn't give us the ability to mutate an existing object's prototype chain (so it doesn't solve the Array "inheritance" problem)

Comment: Note that not all browser support Object.create yet. Douglas Crockford has a workaround for this which is described is his site. However, there's a page that describes all the alternatives for inheriting in javascript (including Crockford's): http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance

Answer (score 4):

Probably:

```
MyString.prototype = new String;
```

After doing this you can augment the prototype with your methods :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
MyString.prototype.__proto__ = String.prototype ;
```

You're saying that the runtime should look at `String.prototype` for properties of `MyString.prototype` that are not declared in `MyString.prototype` directly. But that's a roundabout way of saying what you were *trying* to say, which is that  *instances* of `MyString` should have the same properties and methods as a `String`.

You say that like this:

```
MyString.prototype = new String();
```

`__proto__` is a property of object *instances*. It's the runtime link back to the object that serves as that instance's prototype. On the other hand, `prototype` is a property of constructor functions. It is the template for all objects created with that constructor.